# Video card driver problem in Debian (AMD Radeon R5 M330)

Tags: debian, drivers, amd-graphics, radeon

I am new to Linux. I am using Debian 8. I tried to play some games, but it seems that they are using my integrated Intel video card instead of discrete AMD Radeon: Star Conflict doesn't even show the space - everything is completely black (I can only see ship's interface components). Games with much less requirements can produce the image but they are running very slow even on low graphics settings. On the same laptop on Windows side I can play Bioshock Infinite on high settings very well. So, it seems to be linux driver's fault. I have some program called "ATI Catalyst Control Center Linux edition" in my gnome menu and when I try to run it, I get this message:

```
There was a problem initializing Catalyst Control Center Linux edition.  It could be caused by the following.

No AMD graphics driver is installed, or the AMD driver is not functioning properly.
Please install the AMD driver appropriate for you AMD hardware, or configure using aticonfig
```

I tried installing AMD proprietary driver, but it fails to install.
So, I'd like to use open-source driver, it doesn't really matter, I just want to get my graphics card working.
Output of `lspci | grep 'AMD'` :

```
0d:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M] (rev ff)
```

I am also curios why it says "Display controller" instead of "VGA compatible controller" like it says about Intel's integrated card.

So, the final question is:
What software/driver should I install or how should I configure my system to get my discrete card working?
I am sorry if I gave not enough info - I just don't know what information is needed here. I would like to provide any info you ask.

Answer (score 0):

According to [wiki-debian](https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo) you need to install the `xserver-xorg-video-ati` package:

Edit you `/etc/apt/sources.list` by adding the `non-free` sources:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Update and install the driver :

```
apt-get update
apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-video-ati
```

Reboot and remove intel graphic driver:

> Hybrid Graphics
>
> AMD ships hybrid graphics with Intel cards . Both the cards get turned on in turn overheating the computer and it also makes lot of noise.

Comment: I have this line in my sources.list, but with my country prefix: http://ftp.ua.debian.org/ and so on. And I also have all this three packages installed.

Comment: How do I remove Intel's driver and why do I need to do it?